# Create GMF diagram programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

I trying to create one simple diagram using EMF & GMF in Eclipse plug-ins. I have created one Ecore with two node & connection. I am able to generate GMF out of that. When I run my application I am getting the palate and with the help of that I am able to draw the GMF diagram. But I want that programmatically.

I have created one XML out of that Ecore and successfully able to load that XML into the EMF object. So my EObject is having that XML values. Now I want a GMF diagram out of that automatically. like with the opening of one sample RCP view it should load the GMF content.

The problem is that I am new to this GMF and EMF, so I don't know which class I have to modify or what I have to write.

Comment: Could anyone help me on this...Please let me know if you need any more information. I have done some coding for this..like Now I am saving the the ECORE object using XMI & then trying to load the ECORE object on top of GMF diagram. But I didnot find any concrete solution.Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have resolved this by myself. If any one need help on this tagged me on the question.

Comment: It is highly frustrating for me to be stuck on the same problem 5 years later and seeing you did not provide the code to solve it

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution:

```
    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
    Diagram diagram = NotationFactory.eINSTANCE.createDiagram();
    diagram.setMeasurementUnit(MeasurementUnit.PIXEL_LITERAL);
    diagram.getStyles().add(NotationFactory.eINSTANCE.createDiagramStyle());
    diagram.setElement(object); //your EObject that should be referenced to this diagram (probably an ecore file)
    diagram.setType("Ecore");
    URI diagUri = URI.createFileURI(yourPathToECoreFile + "_diagram");
    Resource diagramResource = resourceSet.createResource(diagUri);
    diagramResource.getContents().add(diagram);
```

It works for me... after many hours of research

PS: The diagram should be at the same place as your ecore file

Comment: You did not instanciate resourceSet, nor d. Where do those come from?

Comment: I have updated the code. Sorry for that:

d is actually diagram

and resourceSet is initialized as:

ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();