# Generate GMF diagram from EMF resource programmatically

Tags: eclipse, emf, eclipse-gmf, model-driven-development

What I am trying to do is to get the GMF diagram out from an EMF resource, programmatically.

I have found this NotationFactory.eINSTANCE.createDiagram() method, and I know that I can create nodes and everything this way. But I am not sure if this is the best way to achieve this.

I think this entry: [create GMF diagram programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055311/create-gmf-diagram-programmatically) shows the same problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @goto I tried to build the diagram manually using this code:

Diagram diagram = NotationFactory.eINSTANCE.createDiagram();
..
Node node = NotationPackage.eINSTANCE.getNode();
..
diagram.insertChild(node);

The question is that I think there should be a better way to do this, because the resource I would like to represent on the diagram is an ecore metamodel.

Many thanks.